# Changing a MYSQL user password by using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, change-password

I'm trying to have a simple form for my MySQL database users, so they can change their database passwords. So far, I have implemented the following files, changepass.html - the password change form page, and pass.php, the executer php. I am not a professional PHP coder, therefore I can't go further. My code has no verification of username and/or current database password.

I'd like to add a simple check for validation of the username in the database, and also the current password, so it should verify them before any change. Like "Error: Your username doesn't exist" and "Error: Your current password is invalid"

Would anyone please help me on this point?

**I know that my code is dangerous, so your suggestions on security are much appreciated.**

**Many thanks.**

pass.html:

```
 <form method="POST" action="pas.php">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>Enter username:</td>
 <td><input type="text" size="10" name="username"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Enter your password:</td>
 <td><input type="password" size="10" name="password"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Update Password">
 </form>
```

pas.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

//Database Information

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "mysql";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "rootpasswd";

//Connect to database

$conn = mysql_connect ( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

  mysql_query("UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('$password') WHERE User='$username'");
  echo("Thank You. Your Password has been successfully changed.");
?>
```

Comment: Do not use deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use PDO or `mysqli_` instead. Your code is also very vulnerable to SQL injections and you do not check if the user is allowed to change his password.

Comment: use `SET PASSWORD` to change password

Comment: I will do that when I solve the verification trouble. Would you suggest your code changes for the security, please?

Comment: Man that's dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to create a first verification on DB with the username / password entered by the user.
If they exist and are good : return true else return false.

If true use a location to redirect the user on a page to change the password. If false, display an error ;)

Comment: that's the reason why I ask here.

Comment: I gave you the answer. 
What do you need ?

Comment: Oh ok, first you have to create 1HTML page with form to check the current login/mdp of user. This html form gona reach  a .php wich will check on the database like that : "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE login=$login AND password=$password;"if you obtainan error display iton the HTML page. 

When its done, say it ;)

U gonna need base about HTML/PHP/MySQL, not difficult. If you need help, say it but try to do this on you own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('$password') WHERE User='$username'");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this can also help for sql injection.

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = '%s' WHERE User='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($password),mysql_real_escape_string($username));
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result){
   echo "change success";
}
```

Note That: mysql_query is officially deprecated on php 5.5.0. So, you can user mysqli_query() or PDO::query(). More detail on **[HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)**